# Print layout refuses to add map

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am new to GIS. Print layout refuses to add map. This happened after I was playing with some buttons. Scale is set at zero and resets to zero if I try to manually set scale. nb this is not referring to the scale bar.

---

Yes. Tried redoing project from scratch, restarting computer, everything. Each time I open print layout a blank page appears, I click add map and draw a box. The box disappears as soon as I release the mouse

Comment: Hav you tried creating a new print layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps it may solve your problem.

1. Check your map settings: Make sure that your map is properly set up with the correct layers, labels, and colors. You can also try creating a new map from scratch and adding it to your print layout.
2. Reset your scale: If your scale is set at zero and resets to zero when you try to manually set it, this could be causing the issue. Try resetting the scale to its default value and see if that helps.
3. Check your print layout settings: Make sure that your print layout is properly set up with the correct page size, orientation, and margins. You can also try creating a new print layout from scratch and adding your map to it.
4. Restart the software: If none of the above steps work, try restarting the GIS software and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Ended up reinstalling QGIS, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Firenze, all ok now except font size needs adjustment. Oh the joys of the steep learning curve, but I am loving it